# Responsive width SVG image with fixed height rectangle at bottom - see my pen

Tags: html, image, svg, path, responsive

I need a SVG image something like the image bellow (open door architectural symbol ) that will be resized proportional but the height in green and width in red will stay same.The colors and sizes are just for illustrative purpose.

[image: preview svg]

I made try with this code bellow but don't know how to make the height in green and width in red  to be fixed when image is resized.

If you can help thank you very much on your time!

```
<svg id="imgsvg" width="400px" height="400px" version="1.0" state='normal'
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">


    <defs>

        <!-- The left head --> 
        <svg class="head input-source" id="left" 
            height="100%"
            width="100%" 
            viewBox="0 0 10 200"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax"
            >
            <rect 
            width="100%" 
            height="100%" 
            stroke='black' 
            stroke-width='0' 
            fill="#000"
            />
        </svg>


     <!-- The bottom head --> 
    <svg class="head input-source" id="bottom" 
           height="100%"
            width='100%' 
        viewBox="0 0 200 20"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax"
        >
        <rect  
            width="100%" 
            height="100%" 
            stroke='gray'
            stroke-width='0'
            fill="gray"
        /> 
    </svg> 

    </defs>  


 <!-- The Quad -->
       <svg class='head input-source' id="quad"
            height="100%"
            width='100%' 
            viewBox="0 0 200 200"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMinYmax"
            >
  <path
     d="M0,1 Q199,0 199,199"
     fill="#ffffff"
     fill-opacity="0"
     stroke="#000000"
     stroke-width="2" 
     />
</svg>
        <use xlink:href='#left'/>
        <use xlink:href='#bottom'/>

    
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok buddy next time too late :)

Comment: I've tried to edit the answer into your answer, feel free to edit more if you like so that your answer actually answers the question you've posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SVGs are inline you can use the same lengths and unites in your CSS as the rest of the HTML page. Here you have three identical SVGs. The only difference is that they are contained in `<div>`'s with different sizes. You can see that the orange rectangle maintains the same "width" in all three.

```css
.small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.medium {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.large {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

rect.r1 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  y: calc(100% - 20px);
}

rect.r2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="large">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <rect class="r1" fill="orange"/>
    <rect class="r2" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="medium">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <rect class="r1" fill="orange"/>
    <rect class="r2" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="small">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <rect class="r1" fill="orange"/>
    <rect class="r2" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice Explained !

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem

My solution is below

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-default-tab="html,result" data-slug-hash="mdKLYZp" data-user="Zoki-Poki" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/Zoki-Poki/pen/mdKLYZp">
  Untitled</a> by Zoki Poki (<a href="https://codepen.io/Zoki-Poki">@Zoki-Poki</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```